# Removing an element from a list of dates

Tags: r, list

I have a list of dates :

```
> listofyears <- years<         list(eval(parse(text=paste("c(",history_sheet$Term[1],")"))))

> listofyears

[[1]]

[1] 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012
```

I have a variable called currdatefromroster, and I want to remove it from this list:

```
> currdatefromroster <- substr((meeting_roster_sheet$Year)[158], 1, 4)

> currdatefromroster

[1] "2007"
```

How do I do this? thanks!

ps. I have already tried setting it to NULL but I get an error when I do this.

Comment: I can't really follow your example, but I'd encourage you to not do things like `eval(parse(text="c("...`.  That is bound to cause all sorts of problems. Just do `history_sheet$Term[1]` instead I think.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a list of a single vector, but you just need to subset: `listofyears <- listofyears[[1]][listofyears != currdatefromroster]` Wrap it in `list` if you _really_ want it to keep the list structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty solution, that lets you keep the list structure.

```
listofyears <- list(c("2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011" , "2012"))
currdatefromroster <- "2007"

remove.this.element <- which(listofyears[[1]] == currdatefromroster)
listofyears <- listofyears[[1]][-remove.this.element]
listofyears
```